# How do I use OpenStack and Keystone with juju?

Tags: cloud, juju

We are currently have a ( mostly ) working OpenStack infrastructure running ( just missing Swift ) and would like to try using juju to deploy our applications to it.

We just can't find documentation to help support us in that endeavor.

We use keystone ( and horizon ) as our front end and it works.  We're not sure how the environments file should be built using the keystone username / password.

We still have nova-objectstore running.  We're not ready to go to Swift just yet.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you finally made it work? I've found the correct parameters in horizon but `juju bootstrap` won't work. I've asked on serverfault : http://serverfault.com/questions/409222/steps-to-use-juju-to-orchestrate-a-devstack-fresh-vm-setup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is basically answered here:

[How can I configure multiple deployment environments for juju?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65364/how-can-i-configure-multiple-deployment-environments-for-juju)

You just need to explicitly set the right keys in environments.yaml, specifically `ec2-uri`, `s3-uri`, `access-key`, `default-image-id` and `secret-key`.

Your keystone bits should be producing the access key ID and secret key that will be used to populate those fields.

Comment: Thank you.  How do you get keystone to provide you the access and secret key?

Comment: That sounds like a good question for askubuntu or even serverfault.

Comment: @bbrietzke He means you might want to repost your new question as a new post.

Answer (score 4):

Your environments.yaml is basically the same as it was without keystone.  The only difference is where you're getting your access-key and secret-key from.  Using the deprecated auth system, the 'nova-manage project zipfile' spat out a zip archive that contained all of this per project.  Now, you need to create the EC2 credentials in keystone for specific user:

keystone-manage credentials add somekeystoneuser EC2 heraccesskey hersecretkey

These get set in the environments.yaml as usual:

```
juju: environments
  openstack:
    type: ec2
    control-bucket: openstack-bucket
    admin-secret: fooooooo
    access-key: heraccesskey
    secret-key: hersecretkey
    ec2-uri:  http://nova.api.server:8773/services/Cloud
    s3-uri: http://nova.api.server:3333
    ec2-key-name: keypairname
    default-image-id: ami-00000004
    default-series: precise
```