# How can I get juju running on eucalyptus?

Tags: juju

I've a small private cloud running on UEC 11.04 and Eucalyptus, and everything works fine. But I still look for a software deployment solution better  than writing scripts manually. The new juju seems perfect for my purpose . And even though the [official FAQ](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/faq.html) says it can only support EC2 (currently),  I've seen someone has show a `environment.yaml` [containing the OpenStack section](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65364/how-can-i-configure-multiple-deployment-environments-for-juju).

But when I try it to bootstrap from a similar config, juju will throw `HTTP 500 ERROR` or **still connect to AWS** and complained that the access keys is not in records.

So does anyone run juju on OpenStack or Eucalyptus successfully ? I couldn't find any article about it. Or can somebody tell me the main difficult to implement that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that the success or failure of making juju work with Walrus depends on this bug in txaws:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/txaws/+bug/907450

Its arguable that this is not so much a bug in txaws but a bug in the way walrus is setup, since amazon doesn't have the leading / in their S3 service. So the answer is most likely that to make this work, you need to have Walrus accessible without a leading path.